# Half donut with an arrow pointing to progress Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I want a half donut chart with a simple pointer that shows the current progress.

Is it at all possible to achieve the following: (ignore the poor overlapping borders)

[image: halfdonutmarker]

I currently have this:

[image: currentchart]

Currently I have set it up using an options array through PHP because I'm using quickchart.io to render the image in a PDF. Below you can find the config I'm currently using.

```
        $options = [
        'type' => 'doughnut',
        'data' => [
            'labels' => ["Red", "Orange", "Green"],
            'datasets' => [
                [
                    'label' => 'Doel',
                    'data' => ['120', '60'],
                    'backgroundColor' => [
                        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'
                    ],
                    'borderWidth' => 0
                ]]
        ],
        'options' => [
            'rotation' => M_PI,
            'circumference' => M_PI,
            'cutoutPercentage' => 75,
            'legend' => [
                'display' => false
            ],
            'tooltip' => [
                'enabled' => false
            ],
            'plugins' => [
                'datalabels' => ['display' => false],
                'doughnutlabel' => [
                    'labels' => [
                        ['text' => ''],
                        ['text' => ''],
                        ['text' => ''],
                        [
                            'text' => '80%',
                            'color' => '#000',
                            'font' => [
                                'size' => '30'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ];
```